# Java Spring - Ignore Null values in nested object class on GET

Tags: java, spring, jackson

So, I have a bit of strange behavior.  In my Spring app, I have two object classes, with one class nested inside the other. I'm using Jackson to Serialize my Object classes into JSON.  In my second object class (ObjectB), I have 4 fields.  Based on some UI condition, I either set field 1 and 2, or 3 and 4, but never all of them at once.  I've included the Jackson annotation to ignore null fields, and it works.  In my DB, after I submit, I only see field 1 and 2 OR 3 and 4.

The issue comes when I get my data from the DB.  To map the JSON into my Object class, I have to set the fields in my ObjectB class when parsing ObjectA.  This leads me to see all 4 fields being returned, with half of their values showing as null.  I print this info to my UI, so I want to make it more readable by not having the null values being returned.  Is there anyway to do this?  I'll post a code example of what I am trying to do.

**ObjectA.class**

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, isGetterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ObjectA {

   String field_A1;
   String field_A2;
   ObjectB field_A3;

   //Getters and Setters
}
```

**ObjectB.class**

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, isGetterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ObjectB {

   String field_B1;
   String field_B2;
   String field_B3;
   String field_B4;

   //Getters and Setters
}
```

Data in DB - `Object1:{field_A1:"abc",field_A2:"def",field_A3:{field_B1:"ghi",field_B2:"jkl"}}`

**Mapping logic for Class ObjectA**

```
ObjectA objA = new ObjectA();
...
ObjectB objB = new ObjectB();
if(jsonObj.get("field_B1") != null) {
    objB.setField_B1(jsonObj.get("field_B1"));
}

if(jsonObj.get("field_B2") != null) {
    objB.setField_B2(jsonObj.get("field_B2"));
}

if(jsonObj.get("field_B3") != null) {
    objB.setField_B3(jsonObj.get("field_B3"));
}

if(jsonObj.get("field_B4") != null) {
    objB.setField_B4(jsonObj.get("field_B4"));
}

objA.setField_3(objB);
```

Data returned to the UI - `Object1:{field_A1:"abc",field_A2:"def",field_A3:{field_B1:"ghi",field_B2:"jkl",field_B3:null,field_B4:null}}`

Comment: Use @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) as class annotation.

Comment: @LppEdd We are using Jackson-mapper-asl v.1.9.13, so I don't think we have access to that annotation

Comment: why don't you upgrade @user3334871

Comment: @Deadpool Working in an enterprise has limitations, haha.  I guess I can try to see if we have access to upgrade to a new version, just wondering if there is a solution using the version we are on.  Secondly, I am doing the 1.9 version of `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`.  It works for POSTing my data, but not for getting my data through my mapping logic

Comment: @user3334871 btw, working on enterprise applications sucks 99% of the times. I feel you buddy

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure which version of Spring you're using, but from `4+`, if I remember correctly, you can define a custom Jackson `ObjectMapper` Bean.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper customObjectMapper() {
   final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   ...
   mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
   return mapper;
}
```

Comment: Will take a look at this.  We are using Spring v.4.3.8

Comment: @user3334871 Let me know. If you see nothing changed, try setting the Bean as Primary.

Comment: Unfortunately, I will have to re-determine how I am going to go about this solution.  The deserialization works, but the POJO object itself is returned, so no matter what I am going to be returning null fields.  I've decided to filter it out as a callback function in my Webapps GET call.  Since I serialize on POST as well, it won't matter if those fields aren't present.  I really appreciate your answer, and I will upvote it since it does offer a solution for this issue, even though I can't use it for my problem

Comment: @user3334871 ping me if you need help. Thanks!